# iphone cocos2d CCSprite EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, sprite, exc-bad-access

Friends i am new to cocos2d programming and Mac in general!

I have noticed this EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors ruining most of my time... Take the following snippet of code from the [Geek & Dad's tutorial](http://geekanddad.wordpress.com/2010/06/22/enemies-and-combat-how-to-make-a-tile-based-game-with-cocos2d-part-3/)...

```
-(void) AddEnemyAtX:(int)x Y:(int)y {
    CCSprite *enemy1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"enemy1.png"];
    enemy1.position = ccp(x,y);
    [self addChild:enemy1];
    [self animateEnemy:enemy1];
    NSLog(@"%@", enemy1);
}

-(void) animateEnemy:(CCSprite *)enemy {
    ccTime actualDuration = .5;
    id actionMove = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:actualDuration
           position:ccpMult(ccpNormalize(ccpSub(_player.position,enemy.position)), 10)];
    id actionFinished = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self
           selector:@selector(animateEnemyFinished:)];
        [enemy runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove,actionFinished,nil]];
}

-(void) animateEnemyFinished:(id)sender {
    CCSprite *enemy = (CCSprite *)sender;
    [self animateEnemy:enemy];
}
```

here _player is a global variable and accessible everywhere, I call `AddEnemyAtX: Y:` and pass some coordinates. My problem is the first time the loop runs fine... But again when the control is passed from `animateEnemyFinished` to `animateEnemy` then the app crashes mentioning "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"!

From what i figured out, the Sprite reference is not passed correctly! Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow!!
Atlast figured it out...

A small mistake... just replacing the line

```
id actionFinished = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self
           selector:@selector(animateEnemyFinished:)];
```

with

```
id actionFinished = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self
           selector:@selector(animateEnemyFinished:)];
```

did the trick! What i understood from this was that @selector() passes the id of the object which called upon it but at the same time when we use it along with CCCallFuncN it passes the id of the Node just parent to the object which called upon it!

Answer (score 1):

`CCSprite *enemy1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"enemy1.png"];`

gives you an autoreleased object. This means you should not call

`[enemy1 release]`

and 2nd after you set
`enemy1=nil`

you can't do 
`[self animateEnemy:enemy1];`

because you give nil to animateEnemy:

Removing
`[enemy1 release];`
and 
`enemy1 = nil;`

from your code should fix your problem.

Comment: thanx parceval... It was my mistake, actually i had given the wrong mixed up snippet... That code was the modified code i used to store the sprites in an Array so that the reference problem i was facing can be solved!!

Please find the snippet corrected and plz comment on it...

Comment: the selector is wrong
it must be @selector(animateEnemyFinished:)

the colon is missing in your code, means that when the move action finished an unknown method was called. Thats the reason for the crash.

Comment: Sorry dude!! again a typo error!! I have edited the question now to represent the actual snippet!!! sorry again dude!!!